# How do I find the end-point for a Firebase function from a hosted page?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

From a hosted page I can call `firebase.functions().httpsCallable()`, but I don't want to do that.  I have an existing library that needs just the URL.

The endpoint is available on the console, so it isn't supposed to be a secret.  If I look up the URL and hard-code it on the page, everything works fine, but that's not scalable.

Strangely, when I run the hosting locally (with `firebase serve`), there is a function `firebase.functions()._uri()` that returns the right answer, but as the underscore warns, it isn't available in a production deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know the URL, you'll have to build it yourself based on what you know.  It's very predictable.  You will need to know the project ID, the Google Cloud region where you deployed the function, and the name of the function.  Everything else is a static value.

```
https://{region}-{projectId}.cloudfunctions.net/{functionName}
```

If you don't know these values, then you will not be able to know the URL of the function.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing the URL, you can simply pass the name of the function:

For example, for the cloud function named "doSomething"

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable("doSomething");
```

Comment: "I have an existing library that needs just the URL."